# Core Data: Unable to load class named...Class not found

Tags: swift, core-data

Environment: Xcode Version 6.3.2 (6D2105)

Why am I getting the "Unable to load class..." when referencing a NSManagedObject subclass?

[image]

I've check the target and it has the 'History.swift' file for compilation:
[image]

Yet, it still doesn't see it.

Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is looking for `PRODUCT_MODULE_NAME.History` class. Go to the Core Data Model editor and the right hand side inspector and make sure it is named  `RicCalendar.History`.